# ¿Cómo puedo mantener la información que estoy guardando en una lista?

Tags: c#

Lo que hace el boton de agregar es que, agrega un "Envase" con los campos que le paso en el formulario, teniendo en cuenta tambien ciertos materiales, que son objetos que se agregan a una lista. El problema es que cuando voy a listar los envases, esta todo en orden, se muestran todos los datos incluyendo los porcentajes de materiales utilizados como debe ser. pero cuando cierro la aplicacion, navegador todo,y entro de nuevo, pero esta vez directamente a listar envases sin agregar uno, me salta que la lista materiales es null. Por cierto, en el primer screenshot en el string datillos: "materiales" es una List materiales que esta en la misma clase "envase".

Codigo:

```
protected void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        if (ChequeoTotalPorcentajes() == 100)
        {
            List<Material> ma = new List<Material>();

            if (checkArena.Checked)
            {
                Material m = new Material();
                m.idMaterial = 1;
                m.nombre = "Arena";
                m.porcentajeUtilizado = Convert.ToInt32(porcentajeArena.Text);
                ma.Add(m);

            }

            if (checkSosa.Checked)
            {
                Material m = new Material();
                m.idMaterial = 2;
                m.nombre = "Sosa";
                m.porcentajeUtilizado = Convert.ToInt32(porcentajeSosa.Text);
                ma.Add(m);

            }

            if (checkCal.Checked)
            {
                Material m = new Material();
                m.idMaterial = 3;
                m.nombre = "Cal";
                m.porcentajeUtilizado = Convert.ToInt32(porcentajeCal.Text);
                ma.Add(m);
            }

            if (checkVarios.Checked)
            {
                Material m = new Material();
                m.idMaterial = 4;
                m.nombre = "Varios";
                m.porcentajeUtilizado = Convert.ToInt32(porcentajeVarios.Text);
                ma.Add(m);

            }

            //creo el nuevo tipo de envase.
            TipoEnvase objT = new TipoEnvase()
            {
                codigo = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text),
                nombre = txtNombre.Text,
                descripcion = txtDescripcion.Text,
                precioEnvase = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrecioVenta.Text),
                porcentaje = Convert.ToInt32(porcentajeArena.Text),
                peso = Convert.ToInt32(txtPeso.Text),
                materiales = ma
            };

            var res = new Gestora_TipoEnvases().AgregarTipoEnvase(objT);

            if (res.esCorrecto)
            {
                miDiv.Visible = true;
                lblRegistro.Text = "Perfecto, se ha dado de alta el tipo de Envase!";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblRegistro.Text = "Hubo un error!";
        Response.Redirect("SeccionEnvases.aspx");
    }
}

public void CargarEnvasesAMostrar()
{
    lstEnvases.DataSource = new Gestora_TipoEnvases().ObtenerTodos();
    lstEnvases.DataTextField = "datillos";
    lstEnvases.DataValueField = "codigo";
    lstEnvases.DataBind();
}

public string datillos
{
    get
    {
        return "Nombre: " + " " + nombre + " " + " " + "," + 
               "Precio: " + " " + precioEnvase + "," + " " + 
               "Peso:" + " " + peso + " , " + 
               "Arena:" + " " + materiales[0].porcentajeUtilizado + " , " +
               +materiales[1].porcentajeUtilizado + " , " + "Cal:" + " " +
               materiales[2].porcentajeUtilizado + " , " + "Varios:" + " " +
               materiales[3].porcentajeUtilizado;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola buenas tarde por favor siempre que coloque código que no sea en imágenes.

Comment: Por favor sería mucho mejor que  añadiera el código en formato texto más no en imágenes. Gracias.

Comment: Ya coloque el código, gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo más sencillo sería que cuando se cierre la ventana guardes tu lista en un archivo con serialización y cuando se cargue leas ese archivo y guardes el contenido en tu lista.

Por ejemplo, para escribir la lista en un archivo binario:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new FileStream("c:\\archivo.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
formatter.Serialize(stream, ma);
stream.Close();
```

Y para leer:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new FileStream("C:\\archivo.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            ma = (List<Material>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
```

Siendo `ma` la lista de materiales.
También podrías hacer la serialización en un XML.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, pero en donde haría todo esto?

Comment: Los `Forms` tiene unos eventos llamados `FormClosing` y `Load`, puedes utilizar el primero para guardar tu lista y el segundo para cargarla.

Comment: gracias! estoy en eso . ahora te cuento!!

Comment: http://imgur.com/5D2JKRj cuando creo un envase y luego voy a verlo listado tengo este error, será que en el string tengo que hacer referencia a otra cosa y no la lista "materiales" que tengo en esa misma clase?

Comment: Checa que todas las variables que estás retornado tengan un valor asignado y no estén como `null`.

Comment: todas las variables retornan un valor, es especialmente ese "materiales" que esta en string "datillos" que es null

Comment: Debe de haber un problema al intentar asignarle valores a `materiales`, verifica que sí se ejecute la parte donde le asignas los valores.

Comment: Te cuento, cuando pongo puntos de interrupcion. hace todo correctamente en el botón de agregar, la lista materiales se carga de 4 materiales con sus respectivos valores cada uno de ellos. pero luego cuando voy  a el formulario para ver lo listado, todo lo demas tiene valor menos materiales[0],materiales[1] etc. porque materiales es null.

Comment: Si el botón para agregar hace todo bien entonces deberías agregar a pregunta la parte del formulario que mencionas.

Comment: en el otro formulario lo que esta es el metodo que subi que se llama cargarEnvasesAMostrar(), que esta en el load para dispararse ni bien entras al formulario para listar envases en listbox